# Sharekit vs facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api, sharekit

I need to integrate Facebook in iphone app. Earlier I thought of using sharekit but somehow I found they do not use latest facebook sdk(graph api). But my sharing needs are only to post on the user's wall, and post custom messages with a link. So my point is should I use sharekit even if it does not use the latest graph api?

Comment: I'm not an iPhone developer but I guess there's a Facebook-SDK for iphone with examples with it?

Comment: We were using the something similar in a website, not an iPhone app but we found that the native FB API is useless when you want to use HTTPs. Not sure if it's an issue in your case, but this forced us to use a 3rd party service to wrap the API

Answer (score 1):

There's pull request with Facebook's Graph API support for ShareKit on github
https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/pull/158

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add facebook, use the facebook ios sdk directly instead of ShareKit.  ShareKit is for if you have a multiple services you are looking to add.